# VS Code custom problemMatcher doesn't work

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

I have a problem with setting up problemMatcher for my watch task. The regex seems to be correct, but it doesn't show any errors in the problems tab even then they show in the console. What am I missing?

```json
"problemMatcher": {
  "owner": "typescript",
  "fileLocation": "autoDetect",
  "pattern": [
    {
      "regexp": "(ERROR|WARNING) in (.+)\\(",
      "severity": 1,
      "file": 2
    },
    {
      "regexp": "^(\\d+):(\\d+) (.+)$",
      "line": 1,
      "column": 2,
      "message": 3,
      "loop": true
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "activeOnStart": false,
    "beginsPattern": "Type checking in progress\\.\\.\\.",
    "endsPattern": "Time: \\d+ms"
  }
}
```

Terminal output:

```sh
> Running compilation in watch mode
> Building component registry...
> Component registry built
> Starting type checking service...
> Type checking in progress...
> Type checking in progress...
× ERROR in C:/project/Shared/SizeGuide/index.tsx(180,8):
180:8 Cannot find name 'SizeGuideFlyout'. Did you mean 'SizeGuideInFlyout'?
    178 |   render() {
    179 |     return (
  > 180 |       <SizeGuideFlyout
        |        ^
    181 |         toggleFlyout={this.props.toggleSizeGuideFlyout}
    182 |         position={Position.Right}
    183 |         isOpen={this.props.isOpen}
> Version: typescript 3.7.2
> Time: 32ms
```

Comment: `"regexp": "(ERROR|WARNING) in (.+)\\($"` `(` is not the last char on the line

Comment: That was a typo. I've fixed that but it still won't work :(

Comment: do the individual lines work, without the `loop` argument

Comment: If the second regex is looking for the line and column, the issue is it will match `180:8 )`, but the actual output is `180,8)`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_background-watching-tasks)

> In addition to the `background` property on the problem matcher, the task itself has to be marked as `isBackground` so that the task keeps running in the background.